# Use other expression inside mine

Tags: c#, asp.net, expressionbuilder

I have created my custom expression builder in which I can use C# code, but I'd like to do something like this, how can it be done:

```
<%$ Code: long.Parse(appSettings:FolderId) %>
```

This is what I currently use, but the above sample is prettier:

```
<%$ Code: long.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["FolderId"]) %>
```

Comment: You're saying that you want to use the built-in `AppSettings:` expression inside of yours?

Comment: Yes, well figured out.

Comment: You figured it out? If so, just answer your own question.